# How to rescale a value in SAS?

Tags: sas

For my homework, I need to rescale a value that is typically scored 1-7 into a score of 0 and 1. In this case, the values represent political rights, so the lower the score, the less free a country is, and the higher the score the more free it is. My professor hinted that we should consider using a mathematical function that goes like this: newPR = (7-pr)/6; This newPr score would be scored as the score of 0 and 1, with lower scores being represented as 0, and higher scores represented as 1. Any advice on where to start would be amazing!

Comment: This isn't really a SO question as it's methodology suggestion where you have a few options. And not sure why it wouldn't be as simple as : `if pr < 4 then score=0; else score=1;` which puts any score less than 4 as 0 and everything else into a 1. Rescaling using the formula gives you a percentage between 0 and 1, not a score of 0/1 so not sure why that's necessary.

Comment: This post could help you better than me https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/08/10/standardize-data-sas.html